# Can we setup one introductory price across all subscriptions in an app?

Tags: android, price, in-app-subscription

In our app, we have four different subscriptions - Basic monthly, Premium monthly, Basic Yearly and Premium Yearly. If a user purchases any of these subscription, he will be given a free trial for the same. Once his free trial expires, his subscription will be auto-renewed. Afterwards, If he tries to upgrade/crossgrade/downgrade to another subscription, there will be no free trial for that subscription.
In Google play console, I am able to provide one free-trial across all the subscriptions in my app through the subscription settings.

We are also providing introductory price to the users.
But I am not able configure the free trial like settings for introductory price. Introductory price is provided to all the subscriptions when he purchases it. But we want it to be available only once across all subscriptions. How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

We cannot add the Introductory price to all the plans

As the document states [ [Link](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/140504?hl=en#zippy=%2Cprice-changes%2Cintroductory-prices) ]

> If the introductory period is a different length of time than the
> subscription period, the introductory price must cost less per day
> than the original price. For example, if a subscription costs $15 per
> month (or $0.50 per day), a week-long introductory price must cost
> less than $3.50. For these calculations, a month is always considered
> to be 30 days.

***Based on the above calculations, it is impossible to calculate and validate a single "Introductory Price Value" matching all SKUs.***